# Changing Values in a Histogram Python

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to write a function 'add_to_hist' that takes a character and a histogram and adds an occurrence of that character to the histogram. If the character doesn't already have an entry, it should create one. For example:

```
>>>hist = [['B',1],['a',3],['n',2],['!',1]]
>>>add_to_hist('a',hist)
>>>hist
```

Should return: `[['B', 1], ['a', 4], ['n', 2], ['!', 1]]`

Here is what I have so far:

```
def add_to_hist(x,hist):
    if x in hist:
       hist['a'] = hist['a'] + 1
       return hist
else: hist.append(x)
return (hist)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You choose to represent your histogram as a list of 2-element-lists; however in your `add_to_hist` function, in the `else` branch, you append the item itself. You should append `[x, 1]`. Also, for the same reason, you cannot check `if x in hist`, because `x` is an item (str), but the elements of hist are lists.
There are also other errors in your function (incorrect indentation; use of `'a'` instead of `x`).

In case using a list of lists is not a requirement, there are better ways to do this, for example using a `dict` instead of a list, a `defaultdict(int)`, or the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) class.

It looks like your code has been written with dictionaries in mind:

```py
hist = {'B': 1, 'a': 4, 'n': 2, '!': 1}

def add_to_hist(x,hist):
    if x in hist:
        hist[i] = hist[i] + 1
    else:
        hist[i] = 1
    return hist
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to represent your histogram as a dictionary, as then you could directly access elements that match x.

However, as is (assuming you're forced to use lists), here's how you'd solve this problem:

```
def add_to_hist(x,hist):
    for i in range(len(hist)):
        if x == hist[i][0]:
            hist[i][1] = hist[i][1] + 1
            return hist
    hist.append([x, 1])
    return hist
```

It's a list of list, you cannot directly do "x in hist" as it'll just try and match x with each element of hist (which is a list) so this'll never work. You have to run through hist, getting each element, and then comparing x on that. If you find it, add one to the second element of that found list, and return out.

Now, if you run through the entire for loop without finding a matching element, you know it doesn't exist, so you can append a new value to the hist.